# How to reset height of containers?

Tags: css, responsive-design

On this page http://pjstagingdecorating.com/home-staging-level-2/ when I resize the browser to simulate a narrow screen, there is a large space between each row.  I think it is because the containers are each set to a height of 418px.  I have used the following CSS to change the `height` of the containers to `auto` but it's not working.  Thanks for your help.

```
.dtp-item-block.dt-portfolio-grid-item.dt_portfolio_grid_6.1.omega {
height:auto!important;
}

.dtp-item-block.dt-portfolio-grid-item.dt_portfolio_grid_6.1 {
height:auto!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the inline style `style="height: 444px;"` from `div` with

```
class="dtp-item-block"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the gap by targeting it with the cleaner syntax like below.

```
.dt_portfolio_grid_6 {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

If you are facing the same issue on other pages, you can reduce the usage of resetting height to all grids by targeting `.dtp-item-block` if it is used in those pages too.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `height: auto` on the `dtp-item-block`  itself did the trick for me.

```
.dtp-item-block {
    height: auto;
}
```

I applied it on the `dtp-item-block`, but you can also be more specific. I tried it in Stylebot (Chrome extension) and did not need the `!important`, but that might be because it's the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You have a css selector named '1', that's not correct according to the CSS standards. CSS selectors must NOT start with a digit, that said, this selector:

```
.dtp-item-block.dt-portfolio-grid-item.dt_portfolio_grid_6.1.omega {
    height:auto!important;
}
```

does nothing, but this should do the trick:

```
.dtp-item-block.dt-portfolio-grid-item.dt_portfolio_grid_6.omega {
    height:auto!important;
}
```

More info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters